# Counting and ordering entities over multiple relations

Tags: django, django-orm

I have three tables with relations between;

```
Customer --> Order --> OrderLine
```

I want to know which customers placed orders with most order lines. Using pure SQL, I would go on using following query;

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT( c.id ) AS total FROM customer AS a
 LEFT JOIN order AS b ON a.id = b.customer_id
 LEFT JOIN order_line AS c ON b.id = c.order_id
 GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY total DESC;
```

I saw another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613080/django-how-to-aggregate-annotate-over-a-many-to-many-relationship) which I suspect could be the solution to my problem, but I can't really make sense of the answer to work over multiple relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the max order lines per customer:

```
from django.db.models import Max
custs = Customer.objects.annotate(max_order_lines=Max(order__orderline)).values('id', 'max_order_lines').order_by('-max_order_lines')
max_cust = custs[0]
```

Comment: I apologize for being unclear, the relations are unfortunately not many-to-many but one-to-many, (i.e. one customer have many orders, one order have many orderlines). Does that complicate things?

Comment: @Rayne The reverse of a `ForeignKey` is a `RelatedManager` that works almost the exactly the same as the `ManyRelatedManager` you'll get for a `ManyToManyField`. So it should definitely work without complicating things. 
@Neil You can use `.order_by('-max_order_lines')` instead of using a sorted dict and everything. Then simply use `custs.first()` to get the first row.

Comment: @knbk thanks! I've edited my response to account for all of your comments. Rayne, this should work, please accept the answer if it does :)

Comment: @Neil Just tried to use the `.first()` method in my own project, and then noticed it won't be available until we get Django 1.6. We'll have to stick to `[0]` for now.

Comment: @knbk thanks, I have changed it back. I hadn't seen `first()` before myself, but good to know :)